# Better way to index through list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have this awful awful code where I am trying to parse through a list of dictionaries which contain a list of dictionaries.

I need to output a list of dictionaries with the id and name like this if the id matches a certain id. Something like this:

```
[{"id": 123}, {'name': 'bob'}]
```

```
list1 = [{"id": 123, "job": "nurse", "who":[{"user": "bob_user", "name": "bob"}]}, {"id": 456, "job": "teacher", "who":[{"user": "jim_user", "name": "jim"}]}
list2 = []
keys = ["id", "who"]

for items in list1:
  if items['id'] == 123:
    for key in keys:
      if key == "who":
        for values in items[key]:
          for count in values:
            if count == "name":
              list2.append({key : values[count]})
      else:
        list2.append({key : items[key]})

print(list2)
```

Code currently works but looks like a monkey wrote it! How can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply accessing the element of lists and dictionaries together with slicing?

```py
list1 = [
    {"id": 123, "job": "nurse", "who":[{"user": "bob_user", "name": "bob"}]},
    {"id": 234, "job": "programmer", "who":[{"user": "alice_user", "name": "alice"}]},
    {"id": 456, "job": "teacher", "who":[{"user": "jim_user", "name": "jim"}]}
]

# Input
target_keys = ["id", "who"]
target_ids = [123, 234]

# Output
result_list = []
for item in list1:
    if item['id'] in target_ids:
        result_list.append([
            {"id": item[target_keys[0]]},               # {"id": item['id']},
            {"name": item[target_keys[1]][0]['name']},  # {"name": item['who'][0]['name']}
        ])
print(result_list)
```

Comment: If there are more constrains, I would be happy to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use Python version: 3.8 or above

```
list1 = [{"id": 123, "job": "nurse",   "who":[{"user": "bob_user", "name": "bob"}]}, 
         {"id": 456, "job": "teacher", "who":[{"user": "jim_user", "name": "jim"}]}]
list2 = []
keys = ["id", "who"]
find_ids = [123, 456]

for data in list1:
    # while checking if the "id" matches list of ids in "find_ids"
    # We are assigning the "id" value to variable "user_id"
    if (user_id:=data.get("id")) in find_ids:
        user_name = data.get("who")[0].get("name")
        list2.append({"id": user_id, "who": user_name})
print(list2)
# output:
# [{'id': 123, 'who': 'bob'}, {'id': 456, 'who': 'jim'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this code into a one-liner using Pythonic list comprehension.
Branching off of @Jiho Choi's example of an input of multiple target_ids and assuming the array value of the key "who" only has a single dictionary item, this would be your most concise solution:

```py
list1 = [
        {"id": 123, "job": "nurse", "who":[{"user": "bob_user", "name": "bob"}]},
        {"id": 234, "job": "programmer", "who":[{"user": "alice_user", "name": "alice"}]},
        {"id": 456, "job": "teacher", "who":[{"user": "jim_user", "name": "jim"}]}
        ]
# Input
target_ids = [123, 234]

# Output
result_list = [[{'id': x['id']}, {'who': x['who'][0]['name']}] for x in list1 if x['id'] in target_ids]
print(result_list)
```